# Deleting value present in a neighbor column

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to write a python3 script that will remove the value present in other column.

For example:

```
A   A,B,C
T   H,D,T
H   A,H,D,C
```

will be:

```
A   B,C
T   H,D
H   A,D,C
```

Assuming these are 4th (ref) and 5th (alt) column of my datasheet
I wrote the following code:

```
with open(two) as infile, open (three, 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    for g, pos, code, ref, alt, *rest in reader:
        a = alt.split(',')
        if a == ref:
            writer.writerow([g, pos, code, ref, [alt-ref]] + rest)
        if a != ref:
            writer.writerow([g, pos, code, ref, alt] + rest)
```

So I meant to write it so that 
If the letter in "ref" equals to any splitted string in "alt", that value is deleted from "alt" and exported.
If not, the row is exported as it is.
[alt-ref] does not seem to work.

Can someone help me complete this code? 
I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like that,

```
[x for x in alt if x != ref]
```

Create a new list without value ref`