# Removing value from different column

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to write an output file with 4th column (ref) value deleted from 5th column (alt) if the same value is present.

Here is the code I have:

```
with open(two) as infile, open (three, 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')

    for g, pos, code, ref, alt, *rest in reader:
        a = alt.split(',')
        b = [x for x in a]
        if b == ref:
            writer.writerow([g, pos, code, ref, [alt-ref]] + rest)
        if b != ref:
            writer.writerow([g, pos, code, ref, alt] + rest)
```

I know [alt-ref] does not work. I am not sure which function can substitute this part.
My infile for 4th and 5th column would look like this:

```
A   A,B,C
T   H,D,T
H   A,H,D,C
```

and my desired output:

```
A   B,C
T   H,D
H   A,D,C
```

can someone help me? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Do you've multiple accounts? [Deleting value present in a neighbor column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796416/deleting-value-present-in-a-neighbor-column)

Comment: I think that is from my account. If its not, I probably logged in to wrong gmail. My apologies..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to delete and filter items. Check this quick example to do that.

**Note:** we're not stressing the point on how to open/write new Files.

```
data= """A  A,B,C
T  H,D,T
H  A,H,D,C"""
newFile=""
for line in data.splitlines():  #Reading the sequence 
    ref,alt= line.split("  ") #splitting lines, to get ref/alt columns
    altList= alt.split(",")   #splitting alt to get items 
    l= list(set(altList)-set(ref)) #  delete from alt if the same value is present in ref.
    newLine= " ".join([ref,",".join(l)]) #rewriting the data
    newFile+=newLine+'\n'
    #print newLine

print newFile
```

Output:

```
A C,B
T H,D
H A,C,D
```